# In my vis.js stacked bar chart, how do I move my labels to the correct location?

Tags: javascript, vis.js

Here's the code for my stacked bar chart:

```
var barGraphDiv = document.createElement('div');
barGraphCombinedDiv.appendChild(barGraphDiv);
var groups = new vis.DataSet();
groups.add({id: 0, content: "group0",})
groups.add({id: 1, content: "group1",})
groups.add({id: 2, content: "group2",})

var items = [
    {x: '2014-06-11', y: 10, group:0, label: {content: 10, xOffset: -25}},
    {x: '2014-06-12', y: 25, group:0, label: {content: 25, xOffset: -25}},
    {x: '2014-06-13', y: 30, group:0, label: {content: 30, xOffset: -25}},
    {x: '2014-06-14', y: 10, group:0, label: {content: 10, xOffset: -25}},
    {x: '2014-06-15', y: 15, group:0, label: {content: 15, xOffset: -25}},
    {x: '2014-06-16', y: 30, group:0, label: {content: 30, xOffset: -25}},
    {x: '2014-06-11', y: 12, group:1, label: {content: 12, xOffset: -25}},
    {x: '2014-06-12', y: 15, group:1, label: {content: 15, xOffset: -25}},
    {x: '2014-06-13', y: 34, group:1, label: {content: 34, xOffset: -25}},
    {x: '2014-06-14', y: 24, group:1, label: {content: 24, xOffset: -25}},
    {x: '2014-06-15', y: 5,  group:1, label: {content: 5, xOffset: -25}},
    {x: '2014-06-16', y: 12, group:1, label: {content: 12, xOffset: -25}},
    {x: '2014-06-11', y: 22, group:2, label: {content: 22, xOffset: -25}},
    {x: '2014-06-12', y: 14, group:2},
    {x: '2014-06-13', y: 24, group:2, label: {content: 24, xOffset: -25}},
    {x: '2014-06-14', y: 21, group:2, label: {content: 21, xOffset: -25}},
    {x: '2014-06-15', y: 30, group:2},
    {x: '2014-06-16', y: 18, group:2}
];

var dataset = new vis.DataSet(items);
var options = {
    style:'bar',
    stack:true,
    barChart: {width:50, align:'center', sideBySide:true},
    drawPoints: {
        size: 0,
    },
    dataAxis: {
        icons:true
    },
    orientation:'top',
    start: '2014-06-10',
    end: '2014-06-18',
};
var graph2d = new vis.Graph2d(barGraphDiv, items, groups, options);
```

This produces a bar chart that looks like this:
[image: stacked chart]

How would I get the labels to line up with the groups? Basically the labels need to be shifted up like the groups.

The bottom label is in the correct location. The others are not. When I do an inspect element, the first bar looks like this:

```
<rect class="vis-graph-group0 vis-bar" height="33.33333333333337" width="50" y="300" x="1956.375">
</rect>
<rect class="vis-graph-group0 vis-point" height="0" width="0" y="300" x="1981.375">
</rect>
<text y="300" x="1956.375">10</text>
<rect class="vis-graph-group1 vis-bar" height="40.33333333333337" width="50" y="259.66666666666663" x="1956.375">
</rect>
<rect class="vis-graph-group1 vis-point" height="0" width="0" y="293" x="1981.375">
</rect>
<text y="293" x="1956.375">12</text>
<rect class="vis-graph-group2 vis-bar" height="73.33333333333337" width="50" y="186.33333333333326" x="1956.375">
</rect>
<rect class="vis-graph-group2 vis-point" height="0" width="0" y="260" x="1981.375">
</rect>
<text y="260" x="1956.375">22</text>
```

What I have noticed is that the y value for the text elements needs to be modified. The bottom most text element has the correct y value. The next to bottom one needs the y value changed to the previous text element's y value - the height of the bar.

For example, the bottom most text element has a y value of 300. The next text element has a y value of 293 while the bar associated with that text value has a height of 40.33333. This y value actually needs to be set to 300 - 40.33333 = 259.66667. Then the next text element's y value needs to be set to 259.66667 - 73.33333 = 186.33334.

How would I go about accomplishing this? Is there an easier to shift the labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm one of the developers of visjs. It seems like this is a bug. I'm not sure when this will be fixed as it's very busy currently. As for an easier way, I don't think so. If everything worked the way it should you shouldn't have to do anything for this.

We plan on a huge refactor of the graph2d but as it stands we do not have the manpower available to undertake this in the near future.

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex! Hopefully I'll be able to figure it out on my own or someone else has been able to do this. Good luck with the refactor! PS, would you like me to file a bug report?

Comment: So I figured out a way to change the y-values of all the labels and move them manually. However, as soon as my code finishes, after all the y-values are changed, all the labels move back to their original positions. Do you know what's going on there?

Comment: There's a redraw cycle running in the component. It turned out to be a small bug so I've fixed it and pushed the fix to our develop branch. We'll add it in the next release.